# Assign F5 for browser refresh using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a autohotkey script which performs browser refresh for F5. My PC has a media key assignment for F5 , so for browser refresh I have to press Fn+F5. What I want is for it to perform the refresh just on pressing F5.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
f5::Send, {Browser_Refresh}
```

or

```
f5::Send, ^r
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a similar problem I once had with an HP laptop. HP had decided to put their control keys (wifi, sound, screen brightness, etc) on the standard function keys. If you wanted to use any "normal" function key you also had to press the Fn key.

I don't know your brand (HP, Dell, etc), so best to Google for: *"your brand" disable Fn and function key*. You will most likely need to change this in your bios.

Hope this helps.

Alternatively, you could select any other combination like *[Alt]-R* and link it to *send, {F5}*.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle this behavior either in the BIOS or the Windows Mobility Center (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) depending on your laptop brand.

By toggle, I mean, you will have to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to use corresponding media feature.

You can use [@Honest Abe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657882/3357935) as well.